# Extracting data from the payload in Djnago Rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I have a payload of data sent from the frontend. It is a post api call to create a product object and a variant object at the same time. But I am having difficulties in extracting the ids from the validated_data (category_ids)

The data sent is like this:

```
name: Soap
category[0]: 7
category[1]: 23
brand: 7
collection: 11
availability: in_stock
warranty: no_warranty
service: cash_on_delivery
rating: 3
best_seller: true
top_rated: true
featured: true
main_product_image: (binary)
merchant: 2
variants[0][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[0][price]: 127
variants[0][quantity]: 1
variants[0][color]: red
variants[0][size]: M
variants[0][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[0][variant_image]: (binary)
variants[1][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[1][price]: 127
variants[1][quantity]: 1
variants[1][color]: red
variants[1][size]: M
variants[1][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[1][variant_image]: (binary
```

My view:

```
class ProductAddAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]    
    parser_classes = [MultipartJsonParser]
    serializer_class = AddProductSerializer
```

My serializer:

```
class  AddProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','merchant','featured', 'top_rated','category','brand','collection','sub_category',
                  'name','slug','description', 'main_product_image','best_seller','picture',
                  'rating','availability','warranty','services','variants']
        #depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
         #user = self.context['request'].user

         picture_data = validated_data.get('picture')

         merchant = validated_data.get('merchant')       

         featured = validated_data.get('featured')

         top_rated = validated_data.get('top_rated')
         brand = validated_data.get('brand')
         collection = validated_data.get('collection')
         sub_category = validated_data.get('sub_category')
         name = validated_data.get('name')
         description = validated_data.get('description')
         main_product_image = validated_data.get('main_product_image')
         best_seller = validated_data.get('best_seller')
         rating = validated_data.get('rating')
         availability = validated_data.get('availability')
         warranty = validated_data.get('warranty')
         services = validated_data.get('services')

        #variants_logic


         variants_data = validated_data.get('variants')
         #breakpoint()
         print(variants_data)


         # from pudb import set_trace;set_trace()

         #products-logic

         product = Product.objects.create(featured=featured,top_rated=top_rated,
                                          brand=brand,collection=collection,sub_category=sub_category,
                                          name=name,description=description,
                                          main_product_image=main_product_image,
                                          best_seller=best_seller,rating=rating,
                                          availability=availability,warranty=warranty,
                                          services=services,merchant=merchant)
         product.save()

         # category logic
         if "category[]" in validated_data:
             category_data = validated_data.get('category[]')
             # for category_data in category_data:
             #     abc = Category.objects.get(id =)
             #     product.category.add(abc)
```

Here in the serializer I have tried to capture the ids present in the validated data, but cant write the logic.

**What I need is, I need to extract those categories ids sent from the frontend, query those categories using  `Category.objects.get(id =id)` and add them to the product inside the for loop.**

How can I achieve this??

Comment: can you please post the object of `validated_data`. Just `print('validated_data')` and post the returned object here.

Comment: This data is sent from frontend.So, I cant test print statement in my local server. How to solve this. I am out of my wits @JeetPatel

Comment: When that data is sent from the frontend, it says category data is required. The category data is not being taken.